# Special qualifiers for functions in C++

Tags: c++

I have seen code in several places where you have a function qualified by a user defined keyword. For example

```
#define EXTERNAL_API dec __declspec(dllexport)
```

and then we have a function call

```
void EXTERNAL_API doStuff() {}
```

I understand the purpose in this case but I want to know if these qualifiers can be used to perform specific behavior on functions that are qualified with this. For example, if I want to mark a function as deprecated in my class and if I make use of this function call elsewhere, I get a compile time warning that this function is deprecated, use doStuff2() instead. How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Each compiler has its own keywords to mark function as deprecated, for MSVS you can do the following:

```
#define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated(COMPILE_ERROR_TEXT))
```

and you can use it as:

```
DEPRECATED void oldFunction();
```

In C++14 there is a possibility to use [[deprecated]] tag.
Like that:

```
[[deprecated]]
void oldFunc();
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a way to specify custom behavior? Like run compile time code to perform a certain function when a certain function is qualified with a custom macro?

Comment: @shaveenk: Sure, if you write your own compiler ;)

Comment: As I understand you want to call another function when the deprecated is called? You can't do that with deprecated macro, or C++ keyword, the best thing is to call new method from the old one. In general I think it's a bad idea, cause when user calls oldFunction he expects to get the old behavior.